# TextWatcher monitor only current input

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I have `EditText` which is connected with `TextWatcher` I'm monitoring when user presses `@` letter. That will make a `Listview` appear with names of commentators on particular post. When user chooses one of the users from `ListView`, name is `append` to `EditText` and `ListView` is hidden.

But the problem is when user continues typing `ListView` will appear again because `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` monitors the whole inputted text which already `contains` letter `@`.

Is there a way to monitor only what user is actually typing not the whole inputed text? Or somehow escape last inputed word in `TextWatcher`? Or any other suggestions how to solve this.

I was researching but didn't find anything useful. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please type your  `TextWatcher` Code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to achieve this. This is one of them. You can check weather your list is already filled or not.

```
  final boolean isListSet = false;
        public static final String textToFind = "@";
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!isListSet && s.toString().contains(textToFind)) {
                    // set your list here
                    isListSet = true;
                }
                if (!s.toString().contains(textToFind)) {
                    // remove your list
                    isListSet = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This solves one problem but raises another. What if user want to input more than one commentators for example `@John, @Lisa` etc? This will work only if there is going to be one mentioning in comment for more `ListView` will not appear again because `isListSet` is `true`

Comment: I did not think that. I will modify this method, wait a bit.

Comment: I was thinking to write logic for this. But here are many things to manage . I can write this for you. But here is an library that would be beneficial for you. https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass

Comment: I suggest you use this library if you want to boost up things